# php get values from json encode

Tags: php, json

I have an url passing parameters use json_encode each values like follow:

```
$json = array
(
    'countryId' => $_GET['CountryId'],
    'productId' => $_GET['ProductId'],
    'status'    => $_GET['ProductId'],
    'opId'      => $_GET['OpId']
);

echo json_encode($json);
```

It's returned a result as:

```
{  
  "countryId":"84",
  "productId":"1",
  "status":"0",
  "opId":"134"
}
```

Can I use `json_decode` to parse each values for further data processing?

Thanks.

Comment: ...What?  You're not seriously trying to json_encode something in PHP, then json_decode it later in the same PHP?  I'm so confused.

Comment: He might want to store encoded json somewhere for future use

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`json_decode()` will return an object or array if second value it's true:

```
$json = '{"countryId":"84","productId":"1","status":"0","opId":"134"}';
$json = json_decode($json, true);
echo $json['countryId'];
echo $json['productId'];
echo $json['status'];
echo $json['opId'];
```

Comment: thanks brother, work out for me :) very easy and nice solution

Comment: How can i get value from this `[{"countryId":"84","productId":"1","status":"0","opId":"134"}]`

Comment: @151291 `$json[0].countryId`

Comment: @MihaiIorga the right solution is `$json[0]->countryId`, not `$json[0].countryId` because dot is user for string concatenation in php.

Answer (score 25):

json_decode will return the same array that was originally encoded.
For instanse, if you

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo $array['countryId'];
```

OR

```
$obj= json_decode($json);

echo $obj->countryId;
```

These both will echo 84.
I think json_encode and json_decode function names are self-explanatory...