# How can I get a value from a json string?

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON string in this variable:

```
$value = $request->pre_departure_type;
```

With the value:

```
"30":0 ,"31":2
```

I want to get the values 30 and 0, 31 and 2 from the above JSON string.

I tried this code:

```
$result = array();

foreach (explode(',', $value) as $sub) {
    $subAry = explode(':', $sub);
    $result[$subAry[0]] = $subAry[1];
}
```

But this didn't explode the string on the double quotes.

Comment: Is that a string or JSON value

Comment: Can you post that original `JSON`

Comment: Well if that should be a JSON string, then you got an invalid one. Otherwise when you have a valid JSON then see the dupe here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12429029/3933332

Answer (score 1):

If You are getting the perfect answer from your code then i think there is a problem because of double inverted comma. firstly remove it.

```
$str = str_replace('"', '', $value);
```

You will get value like below

```
value = 30:0 ,31:2
```

after that you will convert it in to array.

Answer (score 0):

First replace double quotes and then do the same process as you did.

```
$result = array();
$newvalue = str_replace('"', '', $value);
foreach (explode(',', $value) as $sub) {
    $subAry = explode(':', $sub);
    $result[$subAry[0]] = $subAry[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting your desired result but with quotations then simply use this function to remove quotations:

```
$str = str_replace('"', '', $string_to_replace);
```

Answer (score 0):

your value coming as a json format so first you need to convert it to object and then array and do manipulation as follow

```
$valueArr=(array)json_decode($value);
$finalArray=array();
foreach($valueArr as $k=>$v){
    array_push($finalArray,$k);
    array_push($finalArray,$v);
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = '{"30":0 ,"31":2}'; // this is a json

$data = json_decode($value); // json to object

foreach($data as $key=>$value)
{
echo $key;  // get key
echo $value; //get value
}
```

get values 30 and 0 , 31 and 2 from above