# PHP get info from JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this JSON array in a separate file on my server:

```
data = '[{"name" : "AAA", "year" : "1999", "plot" : "BBB", "run" : "194 min", "rated" : "PG-13", "score" : "7.7/10", "source" : "DDD", "id" : "000000"}]';
```

how would you with PHP get the "name" (AAA) in the array?

Sorry if im missing anything, just starting out with PHP and JSON.

Comment: Your code is missing. Add the code we will help you

Comment: Did you try to get this value from file ? share your code please ?

Comment: possible dupication of :=-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429029/php-get-values-from-json-encode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, you can get `name` from json response as:

```
// your json response
$string = '[{"name" : "AAA", "year" : "1999", "plot" : "BBB", "run" : "194 min", "rated" : "PG-13", "score" : "7.7/10", "source" : "DDD", "id" : "000000"}]';

$encoded = json_decode($string,TRUE);
print_r($encoded); // complete array
echo $encoded[0]['name']; // print AAA
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: @S.Doe: glad to help u

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = '[{"name" : "AAA", "year" : "1999", "plot" : "BBB", "run" : "194 min", "rated" : "PG-13", "score" : "7.7/10", "source" : "DDD", "id" : "000000"}]';

$data_array = json_decode($data);
var_dump(current($data_array)->name);
```

Is this what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some data in JSON format and you want to refer any one of them . You can use following methods depending on your programming language :-

**PHP :-**

```
$data =  '[{"name" : "AAA", "year" : "1999", "plot" : "BBB", "run" : "194 min", "rated" : "PG-13", "score" : "7.7/10", "source" : "DDD", "id" : "000000"}]';
$parsedData = json_decode($data,TRUE);
```

Now **$parsedData** is an array and you can access values using key like as

```
foreach($parsedData as $key => $value)
{
     $name = $value['name'];
}
```

**JavaScript :-**

```
data =  '[{"name" : "AAA", "year" : "1999", "plot" : "BBB", "run" : "194 min", "rated" : "PG-13", "score" : "7.7/10", "source" : "DDD", "id" : "000000"}]';
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
var dataCount = parseData.length,index;
for(index = 0 ; index < dataCount ; i++)
{
     var name = parsedData[index]['name']; 
     // var name = parsedData[index].name;  // or 
}
```