# how to get elements from this JSON in php

Tags: php, json, orientdb

How can i get the values of the field password from this json in php

```
[  
   {  
      "rid":"#145:0",
      "version":1,
      "oClass":"Login",
      "oData":{  
         "Password":"hacker007",
         "role":null,
         "Name":"Nijeesh Joshy",
         "Email":"nijeesh4all@gmail.com"
      }
   }
]
```

this is my code

```
$json = '[  
   {  
      "rid":"#145:0",
      "version":1,
      "oClass":"Login",
      "oData":{  
         "Password":"hacker007",
         "role":null,
         "Name":"Nijeesh Joshy",
         "Email":"nijeesh4all@gmail.com"
      }
   }
]';

$json = json_decode($json,true);

echo $json[0]->oData->Name;
```

I am getting this error

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Sorry it's not Json but php array and objects.

Comment: i have converted it to json using json_encode()  how can i acess the data after that

Comment: Why not access the data before encode it ? You are trying to access the data from JS ?

Comment: i am trying to access the data from php

Comment: See my updated answer, just set the second argument of the `json_decode()` function to false or leave it to default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php get values from json encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429029/php-get-values-from-json-encode)

Comment: if you ising `$json = json_decode($json,true);` getter should be: `echo $json[0]['oData']['Name'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that after the `json_decode()` step, the properties are not protected anymore :

```
$json_data = '[
    {
        "rid":"#145:0",
        "version":1,
        "oClass":"Login",
        "oData":{
            "Password":"hacker007",
            "role":null,
            "Name":"Nijeesh Joshy",
            "Email":"nijeesh4all@gmail.com"
        }
    }
]';

$data = json_decode($json_data);
```

So, you could access the data this way :

```
$array['name'] = $data[0]->oData->Name;
$array['password'] = $data[0]->oData->Password;

var_dump($array);
```

Output :

> ```
> array(2) { 
>     ["password"]=> string(9) "hacker007" 
>     ["name"]=> string(13) "Nijeesh Joshy" 
> }
> ```

**note :**

The classes used to build the original data array must give you methods to get the data in a proper way.

Comment: i am getting an error  
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\net\functions.php on line 67  this is my code https://pastebin.com/2jNdmJam

Comment: Ok, @nijeeshjoshy just don't use the second argument of the `json_decode()` function.