# Handling nested JSON POST requests in PHP

Tags: php, json, post

I am trying to have a python client send a post request which contains nested JSON like such

```
{"nested":{"field1":"response1", "field2":"response2"}}
```

My python code is here

```py
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url="http://localhost/api/vscore.php"
post_fields={"nested":{"field1":"response1", "field2":"response2"}}

request = Request(url, urlencode(post_fields).encode())
json = urlopen(request).read().decode()
print(json)
```

PHP code:

```
print_r($_POST["nested"]);
```

returns

```
{'field2': 'response2', 'field1': 'response1'}
```

but when I try to access "field1" with $_POST["nested"]["field1"], it returns this:

```
{
```

instead of returning "response1". How can I get my code to return fields in nested JSON?

Comment: It's not really "nested JSON", it's just an object within an object.  There's only one JSON encoding going on here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php get values from json encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429029/php-get-values-from-json-encode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If request is in json form then, you should [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it first and then try to access. `nested` key should be accessed as:

```
$nested = json_decode($_POST["nested"], true);
$field = $nested["field1"];
```

Comment: I just tried that. The server did not respond with any string.

Comment: Try `print_r($nested)` and check what the result is.