# How to get particular data from json url

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, jmespath

I have following Json Data in php url
File name : house.php

```
{
"Error": "",
"ErrorCode": 0,
"Guid": "",
"Id": 0,
"Success": true,
"Value": [
{
"MAIN": 225,
"PHASE": 219418523,
"G": "7TH Division",
"GI": "2031892",
"DOOR": "8907",
"Gate": {
    "RG": 2,
    "BNS": "4 Window",
    "BS": {
    "SB1": 2
    },
    "TQ": [
    {
        "Key": 1,
        "Value": {
        "T1": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "Key": 2,
        "Value": {}
    }
    ],
    "MR": -1,
    "MS": 600
},
"AA": "81",
"AI": "8745524"
},
{
"MAIN": 300,
"PHASE": 219418523,
"G": "8TH Division",
"GI": "4526892",
"DOOR": "8877",
"GATE": {
    "RG": 2,
    "BNS": "5 Window",
    "BS": {
    "SB1": 2
    },
    "TQ": [
    {
        "Key": 1,
        "Value": {
        "T1": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "Key": 2,
        "Value": {}
    }
    ],
    "MR": -1,
    "MS": 600
},
"AA": "91",
"AI": "8758421"
}]}
```

I need particular data "G", "G1", "DOOR", "AA", A1" alone to display in my new php file :

completehouse.php in json format  what code to give to get particular data.

```
    <?php
$url="house.php";
$text = file_get_contents($url);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $text;
?>
```

Currently i am using https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor  manually each time by using transform data 
query : [*].{G: G, G1: G1, DOOR: DOOR, AA: AA, AI: AI}  and getting output

```
{
      "Error": "",
      "ErrorCode": 0,
      "Guid": "",
      "Id": 0,
      "Success": true,
      "Value": [
{
          "G": "7TH DIVISION",
          "G1": "2031892",
          "DOOR": "8907",
          "AA": "81",
          "AI": "8745524"
        },
{
          "G": "8TH DIVISION",
          "G1": "4526892",
          "DOOR": "8877",
          "AA": "85",
          "AI": "8759544"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Please someone help me to fix my manual work and save my time.

Comment: i have corrected,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php get values from json encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429029/php-get-values-from-json-encode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `decode` your json and then get the exact value of what you want.

```
$json = '....';
$parsed = json_decode($json,true);
$result = [];
if($parsed['Success']){ // check if your api json response is true. 
    foreach($parsed['Value'] as $val){
        if($val['AI']> = 9000000){
        $result[] = [
            "G"=> $val['G'],
            "GI"=> $val['GI'],
            "DOOR"=> $val['DOOR'],
            "AA"=> $val['AA'],
            "AI"=> $val['AI']
         ];
         }
         // or what you want.
    }
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

see [demo](https://3v4l.org/Gp5tJ)

Comment: this json file updated frequently.so i can't use $json = '....';.  i get this json file in another site url house.php. i need to get particular data and generate json file in completehouse.php in my site .
what code i have to use in completehouse.php to get. is it possible ?

Comment: @MicroJson you can get file content of other server with `file_get_content`

Comment: thank you very much, you saved me,  got all 5 required data,  one more things to fix. i don't want to display data if AI >= 9000000 is that possible?

Comment: @MicroJson your welcome. you can accept my answer. to check `AI >= 9000000` you can add this condition in `foreach`

Comment: Accepted. can you please update code for foreach . I don't want to display data if AI > = 9000000. 

And also result section not displayed 

'{
      "Error": "",
      "ErrorCode": 0,
      "Guid": "",
      "Id": 0,
      "Success": true,
      "Value": ['

Comment: @MicroJson i updated my answer. did it what you want ?

Comment: result section not displayed '{ "Error": "", "ErrorCode": 0, "Guid": "", "Id": 0, "Success": true, "Value": ['

Comment: @MicroJson where is problem ? i didnt get your issue

Comment: @MicroJson also why you unaccept my answer ?! :)) am i didnt help you and my answer didnt answer of your question ?

Answer (score 0):

As you only need to manipulate the Value column so below code will keep all values same but get the specific columns from Value.

```
$url="house.php";
$text = file_get_contents($url);

$data = json_decode($text, true);

if ($data['Success'] === true) {
    $v = [];
    $columns = ["G", "GI", "DOOR", "AA", "AI"];
    for ($i = 0; $i< count($data['Value']); $i++) {
        foreach ($data['Value'][$i] as $key => $val) {
            if (in_array($key, $columns)) {
                $v[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
        $data['Value'][$i] = $v;
    }
}

$text = json_encode($data);
```